# How to match a certain type for a type-requirement

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Is there a way to enforce that a type-requirement in a concept matches a certain type ? F.e. that size_type in an allocator is a size_t or is convertible to size_t ?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. Could you describe how you would use this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that by using [`covertible_to<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/convertible_to), Have a look at example below. Using `convertible_to` you can check that if a type if convertible to another type or not.

```
#include <concepts>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
concept Convertable = requires(T a) {
    { a } -> std::convertible_to<std::size_t>;
};


template<Convertable T>
class Test{

};

int main(){
    Test<int> a;
    Test<std::string> b; //Compilation will fail.
}
```

Comment: Or just... `template<std::convertible_to<std::size_t> T> class Test;` - use the standard vocabulary, don't cover it up with layers of verbosity.